# How to write a custom kernel in GPflow for the covariance matrix RBF plus noise only on the main block diagonal?

Tags: tensorflow, gpflow, gaussian-process

The required covariance matrix is

[image]

where t is 1D time and k={0, 1}

A sample from the kernel should look like:

[image]

with the orange sequence corresponding to k=0, and the blue one to k=1.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a kernel for different discrete outputs. You can achieve this in GPflow for example with the [`Coregion`](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/gpflow/kernels/#gpflow.kernels.Coregion) kernel, for which there is a [tutorial notebook](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.html).

To construct a coregionalization kernel that is block-diagonal (all off-diagonal entries are zero), you can set `rank=0`. Note that you need to explicitly specify which kernel should act on which dimensions:

```py
import gpflow
k_time = gpflow.kernels.SquaredExponential(active_dims=[0])
k_coreg = gpflow.kernels.Coregion(output_dim=2, rank=0, active_dims=[1])
```

You can combine them with `*` as in the notebook, or with `+` as specified in the question:

```py
k = k_time + k_coreg
```

You can see that the `k_coreg` term is block-diagonal as you specified: Evaluating

```py
test_inputs = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.0],
    [0.5, 0.0],
    [0.7, 1.0],
    [0.1, 1.0],
])
k_coreg(test_inputs)
```

returns

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.]])>
```

And you can get samples as in the graph in the question by running

```py
import numpy as np
num_inputs = 51
num_outputs = 2
X = np.linspace(0, 5, num_inputs)
Q = np.arange(num_outputs)
XX, QQ = np.meshgrid(X, Q, indexing='ij')
pts = np.c_[XX.flatten(), QQ.flatten()]

K = k(pts)
L = np.linalg.cholesky(K + 1e-8 * np.eye(len(K)))

num_samples = 3
v = np.random.randn(len(L), num_samples)
f = L @ v

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(num_samples):
    plt.plot(X, f[:, i].reshape(num_inputs, num_outputs))
```

Answer (score 0):

In GPflow, you can construct this kernel using a sum kernel consisting of a [Squared Exponential (RBF)](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/gpflow/kernels/index.html#gpflow-kernels-squaredexponential) and a [White](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/gpflow/kernels/index.html#gpflow-kernels-white) kernel.

```py
import gpflow
kernel = gpflow.kernels.SquaredExponential() + gpflow.kernels.White()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't produce the appropriate covariance. Notice that I would like to take one sample and get both sequences (blue and orange), rather than two separate samples for each sequence.